# Why do the most common words children say contain bilabial consonants?

Tags: phonetics

I noticed that most words that children say contain /b/ or /m/ is that just a coincidence or there is a reason behind that?

Comment: Related (but not the same question): https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/865/why-do-most-words-for-mother-across-languages-start-with-an-m-and-for-fa

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known similarity across languages that words for "mother" tend to be similar to "mama" and words for father tend to be similar to "baba" (or "dada"). The [explanation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/25763/6726) starts with child physiological development (refining motor control of articulators), and these exercises are interpreted by adults as speaking words, whereupon adults decide that mother is "mama" and father is "baba". However, this explanation has extremely limited scope, and there is no general tendency for children to favor words containing labial consonants.