# Are there languages that don't have "mom"?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

English: Mother/mom, Russian: mama, Chinese: ma, Nepalese: (m)ama.
Is there a language that doesn't have some sort of "ma" for mother?

---

To make it clear. I am not asking if there is a language that has word for mom that doesn't sound like mom. In English you can say female parent. I am asking if there is a language that doesn't have any form of mom at all for mother. Looking for an answer from a native speaker, not just someone using Google Translate and discovering that the most common way to say mom is say "haha".

---

Update: this is not a duplicate. That question asks "why are these words similar" (answer : "because..."). My question asks "which languages have the least similar word" (answer : "Japanese", though "haha" is still pretty close). Even deda follows the same pattern. Some sort of Pferdeleistung would be a good hit, but this is just horsepower, not mom.

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/865/363) might be relevant

Comment: @jknappen  Not a duplicate. I ask "what are the outliers?" not "why similar?"

Comment: **That**'s a plain dictionary lookup. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mother#Etymology_1

Comment: Georgian _deda_. In contrast, _mama_ is "father".

Comment: @jknappen that is NOT a plain  lookup because I ask about languages other than English.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few examples: Japanese *haha*, Yoruba *iya*, Cebuano *inahan*, Uzbeck *ona*, Hmong *niam*, Turkish *anne*, Finnish *äiti*, Sundanese *indung*, Somali *hooyo*, North Saami *eadni*. What is not clear in all cases is whether there is also an "informal" endearative word that children use to talk to their mothers. I suspect there isn't in the case of Somali and Saami, but even then infants may well utter *mama* without that being a word of the language.

Comment: Don't forget Aztec: `nantli` or Greenlandic: `anaana`

Comment: @Wilson anaana - I would argue this is pretty close. Compare to apple vs ping guo.

Comment: "Cebuano inahan" - are other ways to say "mom" even more different, or this is just the first hit in a dictionary? After all, English dictionary gives mother, but "mom" still exists.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure about Saami, but _eadni_ is a borrowing from Baltic (like Finnish _äiti_). The inherited word in Finnish is _emo_, which is closer to the ‘mama’ form, but that’s old-fashioned rather than endearative in modern Finnish, and I don’t know if perhaps it’s been completely lost in Saami.

Answer (score 0):

In Riffian, the singular for mother exists (imma = mother), but not the plural. It is the same for father (baba = father).