# Similarities between Sumerian and Semitic languages

Tags: borrowing, semitic-languages, sumerian

I noticed that the Sumerian words for mother and father, ama and abba respectively, are very similar to the Hebrew words for mother and father, being ema and abba respectively. Given that Sumerian is not in the Afro-Asiatic language family, let alone the Semitic one, are the words for father and mother unrelated in each language, or are they Semitic loanwords into Sumerian (or vice versa)?

Comment: You will also notice that the words for mother and father are the same in very many other languages :)

Comment: @Keelan you do have a good point

Comment: A relevant question and answer re apparent similarities between 'mother' and 'father' terms: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/869/363

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that the Hebrew words for mother and father are not ema and abba, but em and av respectively. I believe you are confusing them with the Syriac Aramaic emma and Jewish Aramaic abba

I also edited the question to fix the incorrect use of "respectively" (the Hebrew and Sumerian words for father had been given first despite being described as the translations for mother and father respectively)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, it's worth noting that the main contact between Semitic and Sumerian involved Akkadian, not Hebrew, and the Akkadian words are a bit different—"mother" is *ummu*, and "father" is *abu*. And there was another Sumerian word for "father", *ad(a)*; *ab(a)* probably originally meant "elder" (it's sometimes translated into Akkadian as *šību*, "elder" or "witness"). This makes the loan hypothesis a bit less likely.

But even so, this is a very striking coincidence. Compare also Navajo *amá*, Mandarin *māma*, Swahili *mama*, English *mama*, all meaning "mother". Why do all these words look so similar across the world? Surely they can't all be loanwords or cognates?

The main hypothesis is that it comes from baby-talk, the first sounds infants are able to make as they learn to speak. `/m/` is generally the first consonant they figure out, and `/a/` is the first vowel, so it makes sense that babies' first words would be along the lines of `/ama/` or `/mama/`. The same goes for words like `/papa/`, `/baba/`, `/tata/`, or `/dada/`, which use sounds that get figured out fairly soon after. So the vast majority of the world's languages have words for "mother" and "father" that follow this pattern.

(It's also worth noting that many languages use the nasal sound for "mother" and the oral sound for "father", but this isn't a universal—you can also find many languages which have them reversed! The most famous example I can think of is Georgian *mama* "father" vs *deda* "mother".)

Comment: Also Japanese _haha_ ‘mother’, which is from Old Japanese _papa_, though ‘father’ is _chichi_ (from _titi_), so they have two plosives and no nasals. (And _haha_ is unusual in that it’s clearly a baby-talk word, but it’s been allowed to at least semi-regularly follow the sound shift /p/ > /h/. Most baby-talk words and onomatopoeia resist sound change.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's not that unusual. "Mother" and "father" both probably originate as baby talk *meh2 "ma" and *peh2 "pa" plus the common familial suffix *-ter-s and both evolved regularly (including the p of the onomatopoeic section > f in Germanic and > Ø in Celtic). Onomatopoeias should be expected to evolve regularly, they're just prone to replacement (either from a new onomatopoeia, or another term) if they deviate too far from their source

Comment: @Tristan They probably arose that way in PIE, yes, but they were not onomatopoetic anymore when the later sound changes occurred; they were lexemic by then. There is no Germanic _*fafa_ meaning ‘father’, nor is there a Celtic _*a-a_. Whether or not onomatopoeia change and are then replaced or just don’t change at all is probably not possible to answer; the fact that they frequently contain sounds which don’t exist as phonemes in the language might indicate the latter, but no more. At any rate, _haha_ is unusual in having changed and deviated quite far without being analogically replaced.

Comment: @Tristan I forgot to mention: _*ph2tér_ is likely not ‘pa’ plus familial suffix at all, but rather the origin (along with _*dhugh2tér_ and possibly _*bhréh2ter_ as well) of the suffix _-(h2)ter_ becoming a familial suffix from being just a regular agent noun. That would make _*ph2tér_ lexemic from the get-go, though there is little doubt that _*māter_ is a baby word with a familial suffix.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. The big problem with this is that the people who say that  historic /a/ comes from *h² also believe that historic /ā/ comes from *eh², so there is no place for *māter- in the hypothetical proto-language.

Comment: @fdb I don’t think anyone goes so far as to believe that /a ā/ did not exist in onomatopoeia in the proto-language, even if they don’t accept them as phonemic vowels in the system. Besides, the vast majority of Indo-Europeanists do believe that /a/ was phonemic, albeit rare – loan words like _*abōl_ are rarely reconstructed with a laryngeal anymore, for example.

Comment: if it's just an agent suffix, why does it have the e-grade rather than the o-grade? What verbal root is it derived from?

Comment: "Surely they can't all be loanwords or cognates?" Appeal to ignorance? I can do that, too: *Why the hell not?* If the word is easy to learn, and related to the lip sucking motion, that's one thing, but the fact that this would make it possible to transmit pretty much unchanged is another … that you could only exclude by showing for a significant share of comparands that the form was once completely different. The notion of cog ancy might lose meaning at extreme timedepths, but with infants were are truly concerned with native elements of speech.

Comment: @vectory If there was really contact between Swahili, Navajo, Mandarin, English, Sumerian, and Hebrew—early enough that no trace of pre-contact words survives, but late enough that the words haven't been mutated into unrecognizability—we would expect a whole lot more evidence than two loanwords. The hypothesis that e.g. Sumerian borrowed the Navajo words for "mother" and "father", with no other trace of contact, is absurd enough to be easily discarded.

Comment: the labels "Sumerian", "Navajo", etc. don't make sense for a timeframe that could span a hundredthousand years easily. *That* is absurd. I concede that either way is pretty much unimaginable. So please don't pretend it were easy. The question was simply about Sum. loanwoards into Akkadian.